# eliminar espacio entre imagen y borde css

Tags: css

Tengo el siguiente css, es una imagen redondeada con una borde, el problema está en que me aparece una fina línea transparente entre la imagen y el borde, se puede notar la linéa de color azul en el borde en la parte superior del círculo, que corresponde al color del fondo.

```
.avatar img {
  border: 7px solid #FFFFFF;
}

<div class="avatar mt-4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="rounded-circle img-fluid">
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta no se termina de entender, si la puedes explicar mejor lo agradecería

Comment: Disculpa, ya estoy subiendo una foto, se me pasó agregarla.

Comment: Deberias de publicar el codigo de `rounded-circle img-fluid`, esa parte tambien esta inmiscuida

Comment: Saludos. No percibo esa línea que refieres; te sugiero mejorar la calidad de la imagen, y colocar dos; una donde se vea como esta y otra como esperas quede (claro aunque sea una edición la 2da); así mismo; cuando quieras que modificar un CSS de lo que usas agrega al fina `! important` para que se aplique.

Comment: `rounded-circle img-fluid` la primera la foto queda en forma de círculo como está en la imagen adjunta, y la segunda para que sea responsive.

Comment: Sería bueno que compartieras el código para ayudarte de manera más efectiva.